# Angular: Behavior Subject Value is not persisting in service

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables, behaviorsubject, angular-changedetection

i've created 2 components "search-bar" and "search-results" and a shared service "search-results".
below is my code:
(NOTE): components do not have child and parent relationship. i'm only trying to use behavior Subject to communicate between components and refresh my ui with new results.

"search-results.service":

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class SearchResultsService {

  // Subject to subscribe to
  private results = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  private productsData;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  // Http Headers
  httpOptions : Object = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  }

  bodyJson = {};
  RESULTS_API_ENDPOINT = "API_END_POINT_URL";
  
  getResults() {
    this.getAPIResults();
    return this.results.asObservable();
  }

  getAPIResults() {
    this.http.post(this.RESULTS_API_ENDPOINT , this.bodyJson, this.httpOptions).subscribe(res => this.results.next(res));
  }

}
```

"search-results.component.ts"

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Observable, Subject, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { SearchResultsService } from '../../services/search-results.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-results',
  templateUrl: './search-results.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-results.component.css'],
  providers: [SearchResultsService]
})

export class SearchResultsComponent implements OnInit {
  
  public productsData: Object;
  
  constructor(private resultsService: SearchResultsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.resultsService.getResults().subscribe((res) => (this.productsData = res));
  }

}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let product of productsData.products;">
    <h3 class="vs-product-title">
        <a [href]="product.productDetailPage">
            {{product.name}}>
        </a>
    </h3>
</div>
```

"search-bar.component.ts"

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { SearchResultsService } from '../../services/search-results.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-bar',
  templateUrl: './search-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-bar.component.css'],
  providers: [SearchResultsService]
})

export class SearchBarComponent implements OnInit {

  searchForm: FormGroup;
  searchTerm: string;
  newData: Object = {};

  constructor(private resultsService: SearchResultsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.searchForm = new FormGroup({
      searchField: new FormControl()
    });
    this.resultsService.getResults();
  }

  Submit() {
    this.searchTerm = this.searchForm.value.searchField;
    this.resultsService.bodyJson["query"] = this.searchTerm;
    this.resultsService.getResults();
  }

}
```

```html
<form class="searchBar vs-col-lg-9" [formGroup] ="searchForm" (ngSubmit)="Submit()">
    <label for="searchField">Search Products</label>
    <input formControlName = "searchField" aria-label = "Search Products" id="search_products" class = "vs-input" type="text" name= "searchProducts" placeholder= "Search placeholder"/>
    <span class="search-icon" (click) = "Submit()"></span>
</form>
```

when i debug in inspector, i see the API data being added to the subject. but, my html is not being updated with products data in search-results component. please advice. this is my first time using Behavior Subject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are providing
providers: [SearchResultsService]

In both components, when it is injected into root.

Remove `providers: [SearchResultsService]` from both components. Give that a try and let me know if that works.

Comment: i've been struggling on this for couple of days and i'm so glad this worked. and may i know the reason why we shouldn't provie again individually

Comment: The reason is "Dependency Injection". You have already provided the service at "root" level meaning the instance will be available as singular instance application wide. But then again you're providing service at components level  too and thus creating new instance each time! Since the instance is different for every component you were seeing odd behavior. On removing providers from components, you still have one at root level which gives singular instance across application thus maintaining consistency and persisting data!

Answer (score 0):

"search-bar.component.ts" file call the getAPIResults() function  instead of getResults()

"search-results.service" file remove this line this.getAPIResults()

Comment: Thanks for responding. tried as you mentioned. its still the same

Comment: in service, getAPIResults is to get initial values. and it does show it on refersh. but it doesn't change the values after i submit search.